# How do I mesh my wordpress menu into bootstrap nav?

Tags: html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a custom wordpress theme using html5blank and CDN bootstrap. I have taken the glorious bootstrap nav structure and made it my own. I am now trying to replace the `<ul>`'s
with my `<?php html5blank_nav(); ?>` which currently spits out my menus that are made in `APPEARANCE > THEMES > MENUS` via wordpress.

How do I integrate `<?php html5blank_nav(); ?>` or whatever is being generated inside of those tags to the bootstrap `<ul>` where the html would look like this:

```
          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
/* WANT TO PUT MY WORDPRESS MENU HERE */
                <li><a href="../navbar/">Default</a></li>
                <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="./">Fixed top</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
          </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

```
<?php

$defaults = array(
    'theme_location'  => '',
    'menu'            => '',
    'container'       => 'div',
    'container_class' => 'navbar-collapse collapse',
    'container_id'    => '',
    'menu_class'      => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',
    'menu_id'         => '',
    'echo'            => true,
    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '',
    'link_after'      => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          => ''
);

wp_nav_menu( $defaults );

?>
```